# frame animation window not appearing?

Tags: cs6, gif

i'll do my best since english isn't my native language
long story short i need to animate  a .gif file and i need the video frame editor. for that i used to click this one ***button pointed with the arrow but it doesn't appear anymore*** and i don't know why or how and I NEED IT
[image: im sure it's rather simple but I CANT FIND ANY WAY TO FIX THIS]

Comment: Is this Photoshop?

Comment: @Jongware this is Sparta!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Photoshop CS6 was the first version to default to a *timeline* animation. If you want a frame animation, you can convert to frames by using the menu on the **Timeline Panel**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In short, here's the solution. In Photoshop cs6 click on;

*Window > Extensions > Mini Bridge* - it shows Timeline - then click on Create Frame Animation.

It may be June 2018 but I hope this helps someone. I am still on CS6 which does not have the 3D features (sorry, can't help you with that) or the same Animation set-up... or does it?

I thought I would have to either go backwards or forwards to continue Photoshop animation UNTIL I found the solution. A lot of people have asked where the Animation window is & then been advised you need the Photoshop Extended version... BUT you don't. (Although, apparently, you do for the 3D features).

Adobe have put it in an inconspicuous place. Not sure why, maybe there's a reason... maybe not?  @_@   Cheers all - Happy Creating!